# use date data from database for minDate and maxDate in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have already follow the instruction at

[UIDatePicker - minDate & maxDate from php Var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168472/uidatepicker-mindate-maxdate-from-php-var)

and it doesn't work for me.. i did some changing but not too much..

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from periode order by periode_id desc limit 1");
if($query)
{
    $start = array();
    $end = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $start[] = $row['periode_start'];
        $end[] = $row['periode_end'];
    }

    $minDate = explode("-", $start[0]);
    $minDate[1] -= 1;
    $maxDate = explode("-", $end[0]);
    $maxDate[1] -= 1;

}
```

this is the date pick..

```
<div class=" form_grid_2 alpha">
   <input id="date1" name="filed32" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
   <span class=" label_intro">From</span>
</div>
<div class=" form_grid_2">
   <input id="date2" name="filed33" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
   <span class=" label_intro">To</span>
</div>
```

this is the script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#date1").datepicker({        
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    maxDate: new Date(<?php echo($maxDate[1]);?>,<?php echo($maxDate[2]);?>,<?php echo($maxDate[0]); ?>),
    minDate: new Date(<?php echo($minDate[1]);?>,<?php echo($minDate[2]);?>,<?php echo($minDate[0]); ?>)
});
</script>
```

this is the echo-ed in browser..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#date1").datepicker({        
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: new Date(2015, 0, 1),
    minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1)
});
</script>
```

tried this, but does not work..

Comment: What is echoed to the browser?

Comment: @Mike already update the question..

Comment: Check date create parameters : `new Date(2015, 0, 1)` - The 1st of January 2015 (month have to dec to one)

Comment: i tried to change the `new Date` with the one u gave me, but it doesnt seem to work..