# DISABLE other date which is not in the range of the startDate and endDate in Bootstrap datepicker using the start date and end date in database?

Tags: php, ajax, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

**Greetings everyone,**

I am having a problem in which I need to set the datepicker to be following the semester start date and semester end date such as below.
[image]

The most simple way that I know on how to start date and end date in the datepicker is using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#appointment_date').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            startDate: new Date('2019-1-14'),
            endDate: new Date('2019-5-14')
            });
        });
```

However, I am supposed to restrict the date by using AJAX and PHP. So I modified the code to be as below:

```
 $('#appointment_date').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../ajax/ajax-get-semester-date.php',
                data: {'appointment_date': $('#appointment_date').val()},
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    $('#appointment_date').append(data);
                }
                // startDate: new Date('2019-1-14'),
                // endDate: new Date('2019-5-16')
            });
        });
```

I am not sure what ID should I pass through the data and I am not sure how to append the data for the startDate and endDate. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear about your question. disable two date alone? or disable  given start date to end date?

Comment: @Rasa Mohamed: disable date that are outside of the start and end date. And enable the date which are starting from 14/1/2019 to 14/5/2019.

Comment: @RasaMohamed this is working solution. you need to change the minDate and maxDate as per your requirement

Comment: @vwadhwa Then its nice... I thought it is for two different dates thats why I answered like that :-)

Comment: @Naz Azhar I thought the question asked for two different dates but actual expectation is enable set of dates from start date to end date

Comment: @RasaMohamed: Sorry for the misleading question. I already changed the question. Unfortunately, the solution provided by vwadhwa3 is not working when I tried in my system. even though I already imported the scripts necessary, the date other than what is in the range is not blocked. my code is working. just that I need to restrict the date using PHP instead of hard code in the datepicker itself. thanks for answering btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: Datepicker has an option maxDate and minDate

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  <script>
    $( function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate:'2019-04-5',
        maxDate:'2019-04-10'
      });
    });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*

I finally found an answer to my question. Just sharing here for everyone's knowledge. I referred to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168472/uidatepicker-mindate-maxdate-from-php-var).

In the PHP side, do this:

```
<?php
    //select semester date
        $select_date_query = "SELECT semester_end FROM semester ORDER BY semester_end ASC";
        $select_date_stmt = $db->prepare($select_date_query);
        $select_date_stmt->execute();
        if($select_date_stmt)
        {
            $semDates = array();
            while ($row = $select_date_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            { 
              $semDates[] = $row['semester_end'];
            }

            $maxDate = explode("-", end($semDates));
            $maxDate[1] -= 1;
        }
?>
```

The datepicker that I used previously is of the Bootstrap datepicker. I forgot to remove the datepicker.js previously which explains why the answer provided by Rasa Mohamed and vwadhwa3 is not working. Thanks you guys for willing to answer even though its not really what I wanted.

In the JQuery datepicker side, do this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#appointment_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: new Date(<?php echo($maxDate[0]);?>,<?php echo($maxDate[1]);?>,<?php echo($maxDate[2]); ?>)
             });
        });
    </script>
```